# What is the best solution for this factory method

Tags: c#

Here is my code for factory method pattern

```
public abstract class TestAbstract
{
    public abstract void MainFunc();
}

public class ClassA : TestAbstract
{
    public override void MainFunc()
    {
        //code for line 1
        //code for line 2
        //...
        Func1();
        Func2();
        //code for line 10
    }
    private void Func1() { }
    private void Func2() { }
}
public class ClassB : TestAbstract
{
    public override void MainFunc()
    {
        //code for line 1
        //code for line 2
        //...
        Func1();
        Func2();
        //code for line 10
    }
    private void Func1() { }
    private void Func2() { }
}
```

Currently, function MainFunc in both of ClassA and ClassB has several lines are the same. And I don't want to repeat code in these classes. I move MainFunc to TestAbstract class but it didn't work.

What I want here is how can I just have one MainFunc for both Classes, and it could call 2 functions Func1 and Func2 in each class correct.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)? If I understand you correctly, try the below, and make Func1 and Func2 as override in the sub classes.

```
public abstract class TestAbstract
{
    public void MainFunc(){ 
        //code for line 1
        //code for line 2
        //...
        Func1();
        Func2();
        //code for line 10
    }

    protected abstract void Func1();
    protected abstract void Func2();
}
```

For MainFunc to call Func1 and Func2, it needs to know that they exist.

Comment: you probably meant `public abstract` or `protected abstract` for Func1 and Func2

Comment: Yes. I'll see this solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella Ideally no, the template method should be the only one being called from outside. It shouldnt be non private unless it needs to be non private

Comment: @KarthikT but you must be able to override Func1 and Func2 in the subclasses and you can't if they are private. You should make them protected if `Func1` and `Func2` don't need to get called from the outside. Try compiling your code, you should get a `virtual or abstract members cannot be private` compilation error.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella ah apologies, I was going on C++ rules, didnt realize they differed here..

Comment: what is good here - abstarct methods are protected, so you are safe since child classes will not be able ignore base implementation of MainFunc

Answer (score 2):

This is called "template method pattern". MainFunc can live in the abstract class and call methods Func1 and Func2 that you specialize in your derived classes.

```
public abstract class TestAbstract
{
    public void MainFunc() 
    { 
        //common code
        Func1();
        Func2(); 
    }

    // you can make these protected instead of public
    // if they are not meant to be called directly outside of your
    // derived classes    
    public abstract void Func1(); 
    public abstract void Func2();
}

public class ClassA : TestAbstract 
{
    public void Func1() 
    { //... logic for ClassA
    }

    public void Func2() 
    { //... logic for ClassA 
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for making methods either non-virtual (`final` if it were Java) or abstract, which usually makes the interface clearer and implementations more stable.

Comment: year. Thank you so much. I've applied it success.

Comment: @sll you're right, thanks, I remembered the name badly. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can move `MainFunc` to `TestAbstract`, but you have to declare `Func1` and `Func2` there then as abstract functions.

Comment: Yes. Just like above solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In this example ClassA just executes Func1 and Func2 from TestAbstract, ClassB overrides the the functions. Please notice the `base.MainFunction` as you wanted extra code in the overriden MainFunction

```
void Main()
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    a.MainFunc();
}

public class TestAbstract
{
    public virtual void MainFunc()
    {
    Func1();
    Func2();
    }
    public virtual void Func1() { "func1".Dump();}
    public virtual void Func2() { "func2".Dump();}
}

public class ClassA : TestAbstract
{
    public override void MainFunc()
    {
        //code for line 1
        //code for line 2
        //...
 base.MainFunc();
        //code for line 10
    }

}
public class ClassB : TestAbstract
{
    public override void MainFunc()
    {
        //code for line 1
        //code for line 2
        //...
        base.MainFunc();
        //code for line 10
    }
    public override void Func1() { "func1".Dump();}
    public override void Func2() { }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I'll see this solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `abstract` use `virtual` for your `MainFunc` if you're willing to modify the logic or just a simple `MainFunc` in your abstract class

Comment: Yes. I'll see this solution. Thanks for your help.